# Python and regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following strings:

```
 2 match virtual-address 172.29.210.119 tcp eq www
  4 match virtual-address 172.29.210.147 tcp any
```

The expected output:

```
 172.29.210.119
 tcp
 www

 172.29.210.147
 tcp
 any
```

I am using pattern:

```
   match virtual-address (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s?(\w+)? (?>eq)?\s?(\d+|\w+)
```

I get the expected output with that pattern testing in: https://regex101.com/

But when I use the same pattern to match in python, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\ace2f5_parser.py", line 119, in <module>
        virtual_ip_proto_port = re.findall(pattern_virtual_ip_proto_port, line)
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\re.py", line 213, in findall
        return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\re.py", line 293, in _compile
        p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 536, in compi
        p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 829, in parse
        p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_
        itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
      File "C:\Users\hpokhare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 767, in _parse
        len(char) + 1)
    sre_constants.error: unknown extension ?> at position 53
```

What does the error mean. Doesn't it support ?>. Any ideas on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex in Python:

```
\bmatch virtual-address (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s?(\w+) (?:eq\s+)?(\w+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX8mB2/1)

Python regex doesn't support *Atomic Group* syntax `(?>..)` like PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the flavor of regex101 for "python", you will see that you can not use `(?>eq)?`

An alternative to what you want is to use `$`, to assert position at end of a line. Using `(\w+)$` will catch the last of the string sentence.

```
import re

text = [
    '2 match virtual-address 172.29.210.119 tcp eq www',
    '4 match virtual-address 172.29.210.147 tcp any'
]

regexp = re.compile(r'match virtual-address (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s(\w+).*?\s(\w+)$')
for i in text:
    ip, protocol, url = regexp.search(i).groups()
    print(ip, protocol, url, '', sep='\n')
```